# Fill-out HTML form and submit GET request Python 3

Tags: python, html, forms, urllib

Hi Python enthusiasts,

I am struggling passing arguments using *urllib.request* in Python 3 to fill-out and submit a HTML form.

The critical part of the html code looks something like:

```
<H1>Header</H1>
<form method="get" action="/bin/formula.php">
<ul>
 <li>Overview <A HREF="/kathegory.php">Kathegory</A> 
 <li><A HREF="/bin/search.php">Search</A>
 <li><A HREF="/bin/formula.php">Formula</A>
<li>go to:
  <input type="text" name="id" size=10 maxlength=10>
  <input type="submit" value="go">**
</ul>
</form>
<ul>
 <li><A HREF="history.php">History</A>
</ul>
<P>
<HR>
```

When filling-out the form manually on the website (e.g. *1*) **http://example.com**, the resulting page would be called **http://example.com/bin/formula.php?id=1**

My approach in Python so far was:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse


h = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'}
payload = {'id': '1'}
url = 'http://example.com'

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)
#data = data.encode('ascii') # data should be bytes
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, h)
print(req.__dict__)

with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
the_page = response.read()

print(the_page)
```

without success.

Any advice from more experienced users is very much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use the very popular Requests ("HTTP for Humans") package instead: http://docs.python-requests.org

Comment: if you mean something like: 
    import requests payload = {'id': '1'}
    r = requests.get('http://example.com', params=payload)
    print(r.url)
this does not work and just outputs **http://example.com** ... any suggestions?

Comment: `print(r.url)` will print the url, not the repose from that url.  Try `print(r.text)`.  Also, just for giggles, include the protocol in the url: `r = requests.get('http://example.com')` (I'm not sure if it is mandatory; but I'n finicky).

Comment: this just outputs the html code of the website http://example.com. the website I am talking about is http://kochbuch.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/

Comment: If you are calling an API on this web site, you need to include the path to the API endpoint in your url:  `r = requests('http://example.com/api/cute-kitten', params={'id':123})`.  Are you include path to the API or just the root domain name?

Comment: the resulting path would be: `http://kochbuch.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/bin/rezept.php?id=1`

Comment: your suggestion also results in `ImportError: cannot import name 'requests'`.

Comment: btw: google or duckduckgo etc works fine...do you have an idea what the problem could be here?